# Axis Client Timeout

Tags: java, soap, tcp, axis

I'm using a 3rd party web service that's implemented as SOAP web services.

Per their instructions I used eclipse to generate java stub classes from the WSDL.

After experiencing some long-running requests with them I dug into the generated classes, found where an org.apache.axis.client.Call was being created and invoked.   I set a configurable timeout on the Call object.

I can test this by setting the timeout to something unrealistic, like 10 milliseconds.   When I do this every request times out as expected.

In production, I'm seeing calls to them take longer than the timeout.   As in the timeout is 3 seconds but the execution takes over a minute.

Is there something I'm missing?  Maybe I need to dust off my TCP/IP Illustrated books and reacquaint myself with the finer points or maybe it's just something under the covers of the axis code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to find out how long this 3rd party web service is actually taking to respond to the clients rather than digging into your code since the problem might be at the server side.

For this you actually do not need to write a client yourself, but can use a tool like [SOAP-IU](http://www.soapui.org/) and try sending a request. SOAP-UI has lots of details in the internet if you need to find out how to send a request. Please refer [here](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/working-with-wsdls.html) to get started.